# What does "open recs" means?

Tags: expressions, compound-words

This is entire message:

> As time goes to infinity we plan on having Stripes building products very close to as many of our customers as possible, which is (much) more widely distributed than the status quo, which is (much) more widely distributed than open recs on any given Monday. There will be more on this subject coming later.

And this is the context: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19425274

When I googled I found "open recommendations" but it doesn't seem to fit the context. Maybe there is a typo but I think it's unlikely given the author.

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking the author directly.

Comment: @Lawrence I just did, the thing is I didn't want to side-track the discussion on Hacker News and the author is usually a very busy person (through quite active on Hacker News and online in general) so I don't really expect an answer.

Comment: It's poorly written for sure.  Note that "rec" is apt to be typed when "req" was more "correct", and "req" can mean "requirement", "requisition", and a number of other things.  I would consider the sentence to be marketing gibberish until some better explanation is provided by the author.

Comment: @HotLicks Definitely not marketing gibberrish, you can look at the post commented on which he wrote, also he has 122 833 points on Hacker News, third most upvoted person in this little community.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a company-specific term. (e.g. Stripe in this case)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence does border on marketing gibberish; a collection of buzz-words designed to pass as informed opinions. The term "open recs" here would likely refer to open requirements, that is yet unfilled requests for material or employees.

Their spelling it recs rather than reqs is likely their using the word they heard rather than experience with the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it and giving additional context! I guess I could rephrase as "which is (much) more widely distributed than open requirements on any given Monday", then to "which is (much) more widely distributed than unfilled requests for employees on any given Monday". So it seems like they are extending their network of offices around the world and will need more employees building products for their customers around the world. (Still unsure, but close enough :) )

Comment: Do note that "rec"/"req" (I'm not sure which) is a term used in personnel management, especially by temp agencies.  Not sure what it means, precisely, but it refers to job openings.

Answer (score 2):

Requisition, Requirement, or Recruitment.

Open Req/Rec is used to reference an open employment opportunity. The verbiage has been widely adopted in the temporary staffing field.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer can be improved by more explaining and providing some references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the author:

> It's industry jargon for "each allocation for a single person which appears on a planned set of hires."